# CodeIgniter SessionProblem

Tags: database, session, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter and save Sessions in my DB.

The following line of code will be executed if the users try to login and the login is successfull (found his data in the db):

```
$this -> session -> set_userdata($account_data); /login-page
```

After this i redirect the user to my dashboard. The dashboard tries now to read the $account_data from the session.
BUT

```
$this -> session -> all_userdata(); /dashboard
```

outputs only the standard session content from codeigniter.
I check the session after the set_userdata call (above) and the array is loaded. But there is no db-entry for this session.
Ok i call the all_userdata(); in the dashboard - it shows the standard content of the session AND the data is saved in my db.

Summary:

LoginPage - Load some Accountdata and save it in a Session. I can load the Accountdata from this session. NO db-entry

Dashboard - Session contains only the standard content of codeigniters session. DB-Entry with this data exists.

Only at the beginning of the LoginPage i destroy the session.

I'm a little bit confused, it seems the session is not "transported" to the next site.

Any tips?

Edit: Test-Case

```
 public function testSessionStart(){
           if ($this->session->userdata('key')){

           }else{
               $this->session->sess_destroy();
           }

            $this->session->set_userdata('key','12345566');
            debug($this->session->all_userdata());
            debug($this->session->userdata('session_id'));
            echo "<br><a href='".base_url()."login/testSessionEnd'>Klick me</a>";
        }

        public function testSessionEnd(){
            $this->session->set_userdata('sid','hasd12312kasdj89d');
            debug($this->session->all_userdata());
            debug($this->session->userdata('session_id'));
        }
```

If the Start func is called, the db never get's an entry.
End func generates a new Session and save it to the db.
i have no idea why

Comment: Try remove $this->session->sess_destroy();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should note that You can not access the Session Data in the same page where you set Session Data. If there is no DB Entry please check your DB Structure and read [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) carefully. Hope it will solve your problem.